# Is there any smart tip to choose seats on aeroplane?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, aircraft, seating

I'm looking for a smart and absolute way to choose seats on aeroplane. For this question, there is some restrictions as:

- The seat cannot be far from both toilet and kitchen.
- The noise from turbines must be avoided.
- The class must be economy.
- A seat near an exit door is to be preferred.
- The model of aeroplane is generic (The tip should be generally enough to work for most planes: Boeing 777, 737, etc.)

Is there any trick to choose my seats better when buying a ticket?

Comment: Without mentioning the type of the airplane and airlines, there is only one trick I know of. Look at the diagram and pick up the seat that suits you most. Usually doors, galleys and lavatories are shown in diagrams so you can choose your preferred seat. I also think this kind of question is impossible to answer in a generic way to cover all kinds of airplanes.

Comment: The Related box to the right has some specific versions of this question. See if any of them help you out.

Comment: @HaLaBi, when I asked this question I'm looking for an answer like What is the suitable distance from turbines, if is most suitable to sit after or before the turbines and so on. Of course there is generic tips to choose seats on airplanes, we just need to think smart and find the solution. But anyway, thanks for your opinion. :)

Comment: I have answered this question... even though I voted to close it as too broad.. your last paragraph made it seems too broad.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5351/444

Comment: I don't understand your instance that the tip should work regardless of type of airplane.  Be aware that the location of the engines varies on different models, which directly impacts your demand that engine noise be avoided.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### If you are flying economy

- **If you have a baby flying with you:**
  Take the first row of the zone you are setting in. First rows are usually where the fittings for the baby basinets are available. Also, you will be close to toilets to change diapers and so.
- **If you are travelling with kids:**
  Take a side of a row next to the window at the beginning or end of a zone. The windows too keep kids busy and the end or beginning of a zone to be close to toilets because kids are frequent pee-ers and vomiters.
- **If you want to sleep during the flight:**
  Take a window seat in the middle of a zone. In the middle to be away from noise (lavatories and galleys) and a window seat so no one bothers you to get in or out.
- **If you are planning to stay awake during the flight:**
  Take an aisle seat, will be easier for you to get out and in anytime you want to stretch your legs or just to get little social in the plane.
- **You are a teacher and traveling with group of kids, like in school stuff:**
  Group the kids in one part of the plane, and take a seat at the very other side of the plane.
- **Travelling with the significant other:**
  Cinema rule apply here, take two seats at the end of the plane either on the left or right. In many wide bodied airplanes the last row on the sides have only two seats due to the shape of the fuselage. No one will be sharing the moment with you!

### If you are flying First or business class

- This is extremely different from one airlines to another, some airlines even provide shower rooms, bars and other services. You will get the best of the airline in these classes, limited number of passengers and many services. So no worries.

**Please note:** I said **zone**, not class. Classes can have multiple zones, especially in economy class in wide bodied airplanes. A zone is usually the area between two sets of doors with a bulkhead separating them.

Comment: That's a great answer -- I'd just add that if you want to board first pick a zone at the back of the plane (higher seat numbers). If you want to get out first go for a zone near the front.

Answer (score 10):

You can get a good impression by looking at [seat-guru](http://www.seatguru.com/) they have seat maps for almost all airlines and of each airline. almost all different models they fly with.

You see the doors, the wings and with color coding you can get an impression about the features of an individual plane. Also whether or not your plane as power available for your devices are indicated if available.

So short answer, seat guru is your friend.

Comment: Your answer is great! Seat-guru is really exciting! I will wait for another answer explaining another point of view, if none appears, of course this answer will be accept as the right one. Thanks